# Variance of 1/X

Tags: probability, variance, exponential-distribution

Given a random variable $X$ that is exponentially distributed, what is the variance of $\frac{1}{X}$, i.e. $\operatorname{Var}\frac{1}{X}?$

Since $\operatorname{Var} X = \frac{1}{\lambda^2}$, is it $\operatorname{Var}\frac{1}{X}=\lambda^2$?

Comment: "Since $VarX=\frac{1}{\lambda^2}$, is it $Var \frac{1}{X}=λ^2$" - a big No here

Comment: Seems this is answered [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/229543/mean-of-inverse-exponential-distribution). Inverse gamma distributions are often used as mathematically convenient priors in Bayesian analysis.

Answer (score 1):

If $X\sim \mbox{Exp}(\lambda)$,  then $X^{-1}$ has distribution function $F(z)=e^{-\lambda/z}$. In particular it's expected value does not exist and hence neither does it's variance.